# GKE 1.1.1 and kubectl delete resource Terminating

Tags: kubernetes, google-kubernetes-engine

A new GKE cluster created at v1.1.1 and using latest kubectl (from gcloud components update) when deleting resources (say a pod) sometimes kubectl get pods in a 'Terminating' state and other times they delete (are removed from kubectl get pods output) right away.

```
NAME                         READY     STATUS        RESTARTS   AGE
cassandra                    1/1       Terminating   0          44s
```

Is this new behavior of kubectl?  I don't recall it doing this at my prior levels.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, it is new behavior in [v1.1.1](https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/releases/tag/v1.1.1). PR [#9165](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33836696/gke-1-1-1-and-kubectl-delete-resource-terminating) added graceful deletion of pods, which causes them to appear in the "Terminating" state for a short amount of time. Issue [#1535](https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/issues/1535) has some more background discussion.

Answer (score 3):

You can explicitly set TerminationGracePeriodSeconds to zero in the PodSpec to obtain the old behavior.

Comment: Link to TerminationGracePeriodSeconds in types.go: https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/blob/master/pkg/api/v1/types.go#L1225. It can also be overridden in the delete options with GracePeriodSeconds: https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/blob/master/pkg/api/v1/types.go#L2044.